I am using bin/pulsar standalone command and getting "Could not find or load main class org.apache.pulsar.PulsarStandaloneStarter"
I am executing bin/pulsar standalone command. I am getting the below error:
Error
/c/pulsar/conf/pulsar_env.sh: line 99: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

/c/pulsar/conf/pulsar_env.sh: line 102: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.pulsar.PulsarStandaloneStarter

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pulsar.PulsarStandaloneStarter

I tried to go pulsar_env.sh file and go to line no 99 and 102. But I didn't see any issue. Here is the code from line no 95 till end in pulsar_env.sh file
#Wait time before forcefully kill the pulsar server instance, if the stop is not successful
#PULSAR_STOP_TIMEOUT=

# Enable semantically stable telemetry for JVM metrics, unless otherwise overridden by the user.

if [ -z "$OTEL_SEMCONV_STABILITY_OPT_IN" ]; then
export OTEL_SEMCONV_STABILITY_OPT_IN=jvm
fi

